# Counterexamples in $R$-modules products and $R$-modules direct sums and $R$-homomorphisms (Exemplification)

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, products, abstract-algebra

Q: **(Exemplification)** Do examples family of $R$-modules like $\{M_i\} , \{N_i\}$  and $R$-modules like $M,N$ such that every of four  question in underline is true.

(in other word for every question Do Examples separately (Exemplification)

> $${Q1: \operatorname{Hom}_R\left ( \prod M_{i} ,N\right )\not \cong_{\Bbb Z} \bigoplus_{i\in I} \operatorname{Hom}_R\left ( M_{i} ,N\right )}$$
>   $${Q2: \operatorname{Hom}_R\left ( \prod M_{i} ,N\right )\not \cong_{\Bbb Z} \prod_{i\in I} Hom_R\left ( M_{i} ,N\right )}$$
>
> $${Q3: \operatorname{Hom}_R\left ( M ,\bigoplus N_{i}\right )\not \cong_{\Bbb Z} \bigoplus_{i\in I} \operatorname{Hom}_R\left ( M ,N_{i}\right )}$$
>
> $${Q4:\operatorname{Hom}_R\left ( M ,\bigoplus N_{i}\right )\not \cong_{\Bbb Z} \prod_{i\in I} \operatorname{Hom}_R\left ( M ,N_{i}\right )}$$

in other word this question is four separate question but similar(may be in one answer is existed for all) . i can't any answer for every case(Q1-Q4).
if you can help me or hint until to aid to solve them (or one) 
for this question we just $\Bbb Z_p, \Bbb Q, \Bbb R, \Bbb C$ $R$-modules. and I think we must work with  this $R$-modules. but is not work for example (for **Q1**):

I let $M_i =\Bbb Z_{p_i} , N=\Bbb R$ then $\operatorname{Hom}_R(\prod \Bbb Z_{p_i}, \Bbb R)=\{ \phi \mid \phi : \prod \Bbb Z_{p_i} \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is $R$-homomorphism $\}$

$\operatorname{Hom}_R\left ( \prod M_{i} ,N\right )=\{ \phi \mid \phi : \prod M_{i} \rightarrow N$ is $R$-homomorphism $\}$

$\operatorname{Hom}_R\left (  M_{i} ,N\right )=\{ \phi \mid \phi :  M_{i} \rightarrow N$ is $R$-homomorphism $\}$

$\cong_{\Bbb Z}$ is $\Bbb Z$-isomorphism.

$\bigoplus M$ in this statement means submodules of product. In other words it's product word such that

> ${"""\bigoplus_{i\in I} M_i=\{ (a_i) \in \prod_{i \in I}M_i : a_i=0}$  for all $i \in I$ except finitely elements $\}"""$

I cannot find the true notation for this operation in help center, so i define this operation under question and in $""",""" $in fact $\bigoplus$ in this statement is not true and just is used for notation in this way definition.
I must be find for every i to iv statement, examples to show...

Comment: This question looks very similar to one I saw a few days ago, but can't find. This one appears to be a much better written version of that question though. If anyone finds that problem still open, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Since this question is marked `commutative-algebra`, should we assume that $R$ is a commutative ring?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen It can be, since this question is exemplification , every assumpation is accepted, in fact if we assume $R$ is commutative ring , we restrict the question.

Comment: @rschwieb that question is deleted.(after hold on many time). I'm so sorry for that text and structure and state of question in previous question(deleted question).

Comment: @Alex It's OK: I just wanted to make sure we didn't have people trying to answer both copies. Thanks for improving the post.

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218493, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739256/

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2526334