# Is $\mathrm{Hom}_{R}(A,\prod_{i\in I} B_{i}) \cong \prod_{i\in I}\mathrm{Hom}_{R}(A, B_{i})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a ring, $A$ is a left $R$-module, and $(B_{i})_{i\in I}$ is a family of left $R$-module. We have:
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{R}(A,\prod_{i\in I} B_{i}) \cong \prod_{i\in I}\mathrm{Hom}_{R}(A, B_{i}).$$
However, I've seen an exercise:

> If $Z_{i} \cong \mathbb{Z}$, then $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\prod_{i\in I}Z_{i},\mathbb{Z})$ is not isomorphic to $\prod_{i\in I} \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(Z_{i},\mathbb{Z})$.

If we use the first statement, the exercise will be wrong. It means that both of them is an isomorphism.

Comment: Generally, (covariant) representable functors preserve limits. The dual statement is, that contravariant representable functors send colimits to limits.

Comment: Your explantion is hard for me :(. Could you show me specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that $Hom_{R}(A,\prod_{i\in I} B_{i}) \cong \prod_{i\in I}Hom_{R}(A, B_{i})$ : that is the definition of a *product* in a category.

On the other hand, $Hom_{R}(\bigoplus_{i\in I} B_{i},A) \cong \prod_{i\in I}Hom_{R}(B_{i}, A)$, because the *coproduct* is $\bigoplus$ and not $\prod$.

And in general since $\bigoplus B_i\neq \prod B_i$ you don't have $Hom_{R}(\prod_{i\in I} B_{i},A) \cong \prod_{i\in I}Hom_{R}(B_{i}, A)$.

Explicitly : if you take $A = B_i = \mathbb{Z}$, and for every $i$ you choose $Id_\mathbb{Z}\in Hom_R(B_i,A)$, this will give you a morphism $\bigoplus_{i\in I} \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ but not a morphism $\prod_{i\in I} \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ because the image of $(1,1,\dots)$ would be an infinite sum of $1$ (whereas in $\bigoplus_{i\in I} \mathbb{Z}$ all the families of elements are finite so you can always take $(n_i)_{i\in I}\mapsto \sum_{i\in I}n_i$).

Comment: I am sorry. I would like to ask that your main idea is $Hom_{R}(\prod_{i\in J} B_{i},A)$ can not be defined, is it right? Because take $f\in Hom_{R}(\prod_{i\in J} B_{i},A)$ then $f(1,1,....)$ can not be defined?

Comment: No, of course $Hom_{R}(\prod_{i\in J} B_{i},A)$ exists, for instance you always have the zero morphism. What I'm saying is that $Hom_{R}(\prod_{i\in I} B_{i},A) \neq \prod_{i\in I}Hom_{R}(B_{i}, A)$ in general. In the example I give, on the right side you have $(Id_\mathbb{Z})_i$, but it has no equivalent on the left side.

Comment: "Not isomorphic" is not the same as "not canonically isomorphic".

Comment: It's true that I simplified a bit, but I strongly doubt that the OP wanted to know that there is no abstract isomorphism between the two (and in any case there isn't).

Comment: Ok, again. With $B_{i}=\mathbb{Z}, i\in I$, take $(Id_{\mathbb{Z}}, Id_{\mathbb{Z}},...)$ in $\prod_{i\in I} Hom(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})$. We do not have element in $Hom_{Z}(\prod_{i\in I} \mathbb{Z_{i}},\mathbb{Z})$. But I am sorry that what about $f=(Id_{\mathbb{Z}})_{i} in Hom_{Z}(\prod_{i\in I} \mathbb{Z_{i}},\mathbb{Z}).$. It can be equal $(Id_{\mathbb{Z}})_{i}$, right?

Comment: I mean that $j_{i}$ is embedding map,$ j_{i}: \mathbb{Z} \mapsto \prod_{i\in I}\mathbb{Z}$. With $f$ in $Hom(\prod_{i\in I} \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$ we have $(fj_{i})_{i\in I} \in \prod_{i\in I}Hom(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})$ . It means we always have $2$ element being equivalent on the both side, right? :( Actually, I do not understand why you said that it has no equivalent on the left side