# Counterexamples in homological algebra

Tags: group-theory, modules, homological-algebra

I search for a counterexample for modules such that $\mathrm{Hom} (\prod M_i,N)$ is not isomorphic to $\oplus \mathrm {Hom}(M_i,N)$ as abelian groups. Also, a counterexample such that $\mathrm {Hom} (M, \oplus N_i)$ be not isomorphic to $\prod \mathrm {Hom} (M, N_i)$ as abelian groups. I do aware of the well-known isomorphisms in classical algebra texts, such as the one replacing direct sum and direct product in the first question, or changing the direct sum to direct product in the second. Thanks for any reply!

Comment: For the first: Take the ring to be a field k with two elements, all M_i equalnto k, and N equal to k. The first hom is then uncountable while the second is not.

Comment: For the second, again take the ring to be a field k, M to be k and all the N_i to be equal to k.

Comment: For other situations, you can see also Exercise 2.25 page 68 in Rotman, _An introduction to homological algebra_, Springer (2008).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015571