# Find an example for $\text{Hom}_R(M, \bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i) \ncong \bigoplus_{i \in I}\text{Hom}_R(M, M_i)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $\{M_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a family of $R$-modules and let $M$ be another $R$-module.

> I am looking for an example which shows that in general
>
> $\phi : \text{Hom}_R(M, \bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i) \rightarrow \bigoplus_{i \in I} \text{Hom}_R(M, M_i)$ is not an $R$-isomorphism.

I have proved that, if $M$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module, then

$\text{Hom}_R(M, \bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i) \cong \bigoplus_{i \in I} \text{Hom}_R(M, M_i)$.

Unfortunately, I still have not found any example showing that $\phi$ is not an $R$-isomorphism if $M$ is infinitely generated. Does anybody has an idea ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think $\phi$ should go in the other direction, i.e. $$(\ddagger)\qquad\phi: \bigoplus_i \text{Hom}_R(M,M_i)\to \text{Hom}_R\left(M,\bigoplus_i M_i\right).$$

To see that it is not an isomorphism in general, consider $M = \bigoplus_i M_i$ and the identity on the R.H.S. of $(\ddagger)$.